# C# Math.Max type handling

Tags: c#, overflow, type-conversion, underflow

I was writing a piece of code that prevents an ushort from overflow/underflow'ing. Before that I try:

```
ushort a = 0; //ushort.MinValue
a -= 1; //returns 65535 (ushort.MaxValue)
```

Then I write the real code, and I expect this to "fail" (not able to detect underflow):

```
ushort oldValue, rate, delta;
ushort newValue = Math.Max(ushort.MinValue, oldValue - rate * delta);
```

Interestingly an error (CS0266) prevents me from building it. While I expect that C# will use the `ushort Max(ushort, ushort)` overload, it is using `int Max(int, int)` overload and that `ushort` values are converted into `int` automatically. Of course when I explicit cast the result to `ushort` this works fine.

This makes me think, is C# detecting that a possible underflow can occur, so it's using `int` to do the comparison for me?

Comment: So for `ushort a=0; a-=1;` is a different thing from `ushort b=0; b=b-1;` (later one fails), interesting... I had always thought the type is determined by the left value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `oldValue - rate * delta`'s result is of type `int`. This is because the "minimum data type" for which operators +, -, * and / are defined is `int`. So `byte`, `ushort`, etc. are converted to `int` first. Then, the result is again an `int`. So you need to cast explicitly to `ushort`.

Or you could use `Convert.ToUInt16` which will raise an exception if an overflow occurs.

Answer (score 1):

C# promotes `(ushort * ushort)` to `int` and takes the result of the subsequent `(ushort - int)` operation  also as `int`. Finally, overload resolution picks `Math.Max(int, int)` for the `Max(ushort, int)` call by promoting the first `ushort` argument to `int`.

Now the problem you have (in addition to all the uninitialized variables) is that the result of `Max(int, int)` is an `int`, which has no implicit conversion to `ushort`.

For more info, you can read the following sections of the spec:

- 7.3.6.2 Binary numeric promotions ("Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.")
- 6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions
- 7.5.3 Overload resolution

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the result type of calculations with `ushort`s is int. So what you need to do is cast the result of the calculation

```
oldValue - rate * delta
```

back to `ushort`:

```
(ushort)(oldValue - rate * delta)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiplications of smaller data types than `int` yield an `int` as result.

Therefor `oldValue - rate * delta` results in an `int` and the best overload of `Math.Max(short.MinValue, int)` is:

[`Math.Max Method (Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs0a3045.aspx)

(since an `ushort`/`short` can be widened to `int` implicitely, without conversion)